# setting up timezone between dokku, OS and S3

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, timezone, dokku

I'm using dokku to host a rails application that uses aws-s3 SDK gem to upload files to S3. When I try to upload a file to the server, it gives me the following error in my logs:

Aws::S3::Errors::RequestTimeTooSkewed (The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.):

S3 bucket is in us-east-1 while the timezone on my server is set to Chicago timezone.

date `Mon Mar 21 23:33:33 CDT 2016`

When I tail the dokku logs, it shows me the time in UTC format:

2016-03-22T04:28:39.425196210Z prod[web.2]: I, [2016-03-22T04:28:39.422140 #154]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready

How can I sync up my time between dokku and OS? Does my OS need to be in sync with S3 time? If so, there is no Chicago timezone S3 buckets.

/etc/timezone

`America/Chicago`

/etc/localtime is symlinked to /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to set all server clocks to UTC to avoid some of the peculiarities of time conversions -- however -- the time zone setting should not be the problem, here.

S3 does not run on local time for the bucket location.  It runs on UTC.

If the UTC timestamps you see are correct relative to the system time, then the time zone setting on the server should not matter.

The error indicates that the clock is **skewed** -- which usually means several minutes too fast or slow, because you do not have your server clock synched to external time references, usually done with `ntpd`.

Verify this.

Comment: My date and dokku logs are the same but I'm still getting the error. Completed 500 Internal Server Error in -374738914ms

Comment: Compare your server clock to the actual correct current time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I made request to my rails apps while tailing the logs. The time that shows in the logs is in sync with OS date output.

Comment: Right, but I'm referring to cross-checking the OS clock with an external reference like http://www.time.gov/.

Comment: I fixed by doing the following: sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
sudo service ntp start